# IEEE-754 floating-point precision: How much error is allowed?

Tags: floating-point, glibc, floating-accuracy, ieee-754, double-precision

I'm working on porting the `sqrt` function (for 64-bit doubles) from [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/) to a model-checker tool I'm using at the moment ([cbmc](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/)).
As part of my doings, I read a lot about the ieee-754 standard, but I think I didn't understand the guarantees of precision for the basic operations (incl. sqrt).

Testing my port of fdlibm's sqrt, I got the following calculation with sqrt on a 64-bit double:

```
sqrt(1977061516825203605555216616167125005658976571589721139027150498657494589171970335387417823661417383745964289845929120708819092392090053015474001800648403714048.0) = 44464159913633855548904943164666890000299422761159637702558734139742800916250624.0
```

(this case broke a simple post-condition in my test regarding precision; I'm not sure anymore if this post-condition is possible with IEEE-754)

For a comparison, several multi-precision tools calculated something like:

```
sqrt(1977061516825203605555216616167125005658976571589721139027150498657494589171970335387417823661417383745964289845929120708819092392090053015474001800648403714048.0) =44464159913633852501611468455197640079591886932526256694498106717014555047373210.truncated
```

One can see, that the 17-th number from the left is different, meaning an error like:

```
3047293474709469249920707535828633381008060627422728245868877413.0
```

**Question 1: Is this huge amount of error allowed?**

The standard is saying that every basic operation (+,-,*,/,sqrt) should be within 0.5 ulps, meaning that it should be equal to a mathematically exact result rounded to the nearest fp-representation (wiki is saying that some libraries only guarantees 1 ulp, but that isn't that important at the moment).

**Question 2: Does that mean, that every basic operation should have an error < 2.220446e-16 with 64-bit doubles (machine-epsilon)?**

I did calculate the same with a x86-32 linux system (glibc / eglibc) and got the same result like that obtained with fdlibm, which let me think that:

- a: I did something wrong (but how: `printf` would be a candidate, but I don't know if that could be the reason)
- b: the error/precision is common in these libraries

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that there is about 15-16 decimal digits precision in a 64 bit double, so an error in the 17-th digit is a natural consequence.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The IEEE-754 standard requires that so called "basic operations" (which include addition, multiplication, division and square root) are *correctly rounded*.  This means that there is a unique allowed answer, and it is the closest representable floating-point number to the so-called "infinitely precise" result of the operation.

In double-precision, numbers have 53 binary digits of precision, so the correct answer is the exact answer rounded to 53 significant digits.  As **Rick Regan** showed in his answer, this is exactly the result that you got.

The answers to your questions are:

**Question 1: Is this huge amount of error allowed?**

Yes, but it is quite misleading to call this error "huge".  The fact is that there is no double-precision value that could be returned that would have a smaller error.

**Question 2: Does that mean, that every basic operation should have an error < 2.220446e-16 with 64-bit doubles (machine-epsilon)?**

No.  It means that every basic operation should be rounded to the (unique) closest representable floating-point number according to the current rounding mode.  This is not quite the same as saying that the relative error is bounded by machine epsilon.

**Question 3: Which result do you obtain with your x86 hardware and gcc + libc?**

The same answer you did, because `sqrt` is correctly rounded on any reasonable platform.

Answer (score 8):

In binary, the first 58 bits of the arbitrary precision answer is 1011111111111111111111110101010101111111111111111011010001...

The 53-bit significand of the double value is

10111111111111111111111101010101011111111111111110111

Which means that the double value is correctly rounded to 53 significant bits, and is within 1/2 ULP. (That the error is "large" is only because the number itself is large).

Comment: @sascha Regarding question two: the relative error, that is, (correct - approx)/correct, should be in that range. For your example, the relative error is 6.8533701764037842e-17.