# accuracy of sqrt of integers

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I have a loop like this:

```
for(uint64_t i=0; i*i<n; i++) {
```

This requires doing a multiplication every iteration.  If I could calculate the sqrt before the loop then I could avoid this.

```
unsigned cut = sqrt(n)
for(uint64_t i=0; i<cut; i++) {
```

In my case it's okay if the sqrt function rounds up to the next integer but it's not okay if it rounds down.

**My question is: is the sqrt function accurate enough to do this for all cases?**

**Edit: Let me list some cases.  If n is a perfect square so that `n = y^2` my question would be - is `cut=sqrt(n)>=y` for all n?**  If cut=y-1 then there is a problem.  E.g. if n = 120 and cut = 10 it's okay but if n=121 (11^2) and cut is still 10 then it won't work.

My first concern was the fractional part of float only has 23 bits and double 52 so they can't store all the digits of some 32-bit or 64-bit integers.  However, I don't think this is a problem.  Let's assume we want the sqrt of some number y but we can't store all the digits of y.  If we let the fraction of y we can store be x we can write y = x + dx then we want to make sure that whatever dx we choose does not move us to the next integer.

```
sqrt(x+dx) < sqrt(x) + 1  //solve
dx < 2*sqrt(x) + 1 
// e.g for x = 100 dx < 21
// sqrt(100+20) < sqrt(100) + 1
```

Float can store 23 bits so we let y = 2^23 + 2^9.  This is more than sufficient since 2^9 < 2*sqrt(2^23) + 1.  It's easy to show this for double as well with 64-bit integers.  So although they can't store all the digits as long as the sqrt of what they can store is accurate then the sqrt(fraction) should be sufficient.  Now let's look at what happens for integers close to INT_MAX and the sqrt:

```
unsigned xi = -1-1;
printf("%u %u\n", xi, (unsigned)(float)xi);  //4294967294 4294967295
printf("%u %u\n", (unsigned)sqrt(xi), (unsigned)sqrtf(xi));  //65535 65536
```

Since float can't store all the digits of 2^31-2 and double can they get different results for the sqrt.  But the float version of the sqrt is one integer larger.  This is what I want.  For 64-bit integers as long as the sqrt of the double always rounds up it's okay.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation - what makes you think that a single integer multiply per iteration is a big overhead in your loop ?

Comment: `ceil()` should help you. It's in the math library. Make sure you pass it a float or double, as integer division will emulate the `floor()` function.

Comment: @PaulR.  It's a very tight loop.  I'm doing trial division.  If I do e.g. `i<n/i` it's two times slower than `i*i<n`.  But you might be right that `i*i<n` is okay for performance but it has other problems.  It overflows for large n and goes into an infinite loop and it does not work with `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Comment: @PaulR, here is more details about what I'm doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556599/condtional-tests-in-primality-by-trial-division

Comment: if you are using it to calculate the max size of some loop for trial division, then just add one and call it good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, integer multiplication is really quite cheap.  So long as you have more than a few cycles of work per loop iteration and one spare execute slot, it should be entirely hidden by reorder on most non-tiny processors.

If you did have a processor with dramatically slow integer multiply, a truly clever compiler might transform your loop to:

```
for (uint64_t i = 0, j = 0; j < cut; j += 2*i+1, i++)
```

replacing the multiply with an `lea` or a shift and two adds.

---

Those notes aside, let’s look at your question as stated.  No, you can’t just use `i < sqrt(n)`.  Counter-example: `n = 0x20000000000000`.  Assuming adherence to IEEE-754, you will have `cut = 0x5a82799`, and `cut*cut` is `0x1ffffff8eff971`.

However, a basic floating-point error analysis shows that the error in computing `sqrt(n)` (before conversion to integer) is bounded by 3/4 of an ULP.  So you can safely use:

```
uint32_t cut = sqrt(n) + 1;
```

and you’ll perform at most one extra loop iteration, which is probably acceptable.  If you want to be totally precise, instead use:

```
uint32_t cut = sqrt(n);
cut += (uint64_t)cut*cut < n;
```

---

Edit: **z boson** clarifies that for his purposes, this only matters when `n` is an exact square (otherwise, getting a value of `cut` that is “too small by one” is acceptable).  In that case, there is no need for the adjustment and on can safely just use:

```
uint32_t cut = sqrt(n);
```

Why is this true?  It’s pretty simple to see, actually.  Converting `n` to `double` introduces a perturbation:

```
double_n = n*(1 + e)
```

which satisfies `|e| < 2^-53`.  The mathematical square root of this value can be expanded as follows:

```
square_root(double_n) = square_root(n)*square_root(1+e)
```

Now, since `n` is assumed to be a perfect square with at most 64 bits, `square_root(n)` is an exact integer with at most 32 bits, and is the mathematically precise value that we hope to compute.  To analyze the `square_root(1+e)` term, use a taylor series about `1`:

```
square_root(1+e) = 1 + e/2 + O(e^2)
                 = 1 + d with |d| <~ 2^-54
```

Thus, the mathematically exact value `square_root(double_n)` is less than half an ULP away from[1] the desired exact answer, and necessarily rounds to that value.

[1] I’m being fast and loose here in my abuse of relative error estimates, where the relative size of an ULP actually varies across a binade — I’m trying to give a bit of the flavor of the proof without getting too bogged down in details.  This can all be made perfectly rigorous, it just gets to be a bit wordy for Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 for a classic improvement (posted a similar idea).  BTW1: 32-bit*32-bit is not always cheap (8 or 16 bit embedded processors.)  BTW2: I think there is a problem when `cut > power(2^32-1,2)`

Comment: Even nicer.  If an answer is going to beat my answer, no shame is being outdone by @Stephen Canon.

Comment: Your counter example would actually be okay  since `(cut+1)^2=200000044048a4>n`.  The danger would be if n was a perfect square say `x^2=y` but the `sqrt(n)` return `x-1` and not `x`.  That's what I meant by it's okay for it to round up to the next perfect square but not to round down.  It's my fault, my question is worded poorly.

Comment: For example if sqrt(0x1ffffff8eff971) returned 0x5a82798 and not 0x5a82799.  That would be a problem.

Comment: Your solutions `cut = sqrt(n) + 1` and the more precise version are sufficient but I'm not sure necessary.  It will hardly make any difference in performance to do one more iteration but I still think it's an interesting question about floating point...

Comment: I made a new question more specific to what I'm doing and why I care about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556599/condtional-tests-in-primality-by-trial-division

Comment: Yeah, 3/4 ulp would be a problem with single precision float, but not double indeed.

Comment: @Zboson: if it only matters in the perfect square case, you can dispense with the `+1`, as `sqrt(x*x)` is exact whenever `x` is exact.  (Assuming IEEE-754 round-to-nearest, and no overflow or underflow occurs).

Comment: @StephenCanon, that's the part I was not sure about.  Since double can't store more than 52 bits and if I have an integer x*x that uses more than 52 bits doesn't that mean that x*x can't be fully represented and so how do I know sqrt(x*x) will return x?  I think I convinced myself in my question that it will.  My question would have been a lot simpler if I just asked that.

Comment: Yup, `x*x` may not be representable as a `double` (in fact, it almost surely won’t be), but `sqrt(x*x)` will still be exact anyway, because `sqrt` is a forgiving function w.r.t. rounding errors.

Comment: @StephenCanon, your added content is great.  I need to go through a numerical analysis book sometime.  I found your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317988/ieee-754-floating-point-precision-how-much-error-is-allowed helpful as well.  It seems a math library (or instruction) which conforms to IEEE 754 guarantees the square root gets the perfect squares right.  Probably this was a requirement created (by demand) decades ago.

Comment: @StephenCanon I asked a relevant question, would you mind helping me here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48782377/6156470

Answer (score 3):

All my answer is useless if you have access to IEEE 754 double precision floating point, since Stephen Canon demonstrated both

- a simple way to avoid imul in loop
- a simple way to compute the ceiling sqrt

Otherwise, if for some reason you have a non IEEE 754 compliant platform, or only single precision, you could get the integer part of square root with a simple Newton-Raphson loop. For example in Squeak Smalltalk we have this method in Integer:

```
sqrtFloor
    "Return the integer part of the square root of self"

    | guess delta |
    guess := 1 bitShift: (self highBit + 1) // 2.
    [
        delta := (guess squared - self) // (guess + guess).
        delta = 0 ] whileFalse: [
            guess := guess - delta ].
    ^guess - 1
```

Where // is operator for quotient of integer division.
Final guard `guess*guess <= self ifTrue: [^guess].` can be avoided if initial guess is fed in excess of exact solution as is the case here.
Initializing with approximate float sqrt was not an option because integers are arbitrarily large and might overflow

But here, you could seed the initial guess with floating point sqrt approximation, and my bet is that the exact solution will be found in very few loops. In C that would be:

```
uint32_t sqrtFloor(uint64_t n)
{
    int64_t diff;
    int64_t delta;
    uint64_t guess=sqrt(n); /* implicit conversions here... */
    while( (delta = (diff=guess*guess-n) / (guess+guess)) != 0 )
        guess -= delta;
    return guess-(diff>0);
}
```

That's a few integer multiplications and divisions, but outside the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to calculate a rational upper bound of the square root of a natural number. Continued fraction is what you need see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

For x>0, there is
[image: square root formula].

To make the notation more compact, rewriting the above formula as

[image: compact square root]

Truncate the continued fraction by removing the tail term (x-1)/2's at each recursion depth, one gets a sequence of approximations of sqrt(x)  as below:

[image: upper bounds]

Upper bounds appear at lines with odd line numbers, and gets tighter. When distance between an upper bound and its neighboring lower bound is less than 1, that approximation is what you need. Using that value as the value of cut, here cut must be a float number, solves the problem.

For very large number, rational number should be used, so no precision is lost during conversion between integer and floating point number.