# Most efficient way to find the common divisors of two numbers upto 10^6

Tags: c++, time-complexity, factors

I wanted to store all the divisors of all the numbers from 1 to 10^6. But this seems too slow. This is the preprocess() function of my code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=1000000; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=i/2; j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
            divi[i][j] = true;
    }
}
```

I used map container like this:

> `map <int, bool> divi[1000010];`

Then I tried to find the common divisors of two given numbers.

```
preprocess();

int T, A, B;

cin >> T;

while(T--)
{
    cin >> A >> B;

    int common = 0;
    for(it = divi[A].begin(); it!=divi[A].end(); it++)
    {
        if(divi[B][it->first]==true)
            common++;
    }

    cout << common << endl;
```

How should i approach now to make it faster enough?

Comment: Look at [Euclidean_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: Note that `divi[B][it->first] == true` will create a new map entry if one didn't exist. This gets very costly, particularly for the primes.

Comment: BTW, `std::map <int, bool>` might be replaced by `std::set<int>`.

Comment: By using sieve method, you might get rid of modulo and division in your preprocessor method.

Comment: The main saving of a sieve method is that you don't examine all elements, module and division are almost as fast as multiplication.

Comment: @Jarod42 Euclidian method will give you the gcd. If you need *all the common divisors* you need: 1. factor the gcd 2. multiply all the (2^n-1) combinations of the gcd factors, multiplicity included.

Comment: There's some useful info in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469430/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-all-the-factors-of-an-integer/35470770#35470770 .

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the fact that using a `std::map` will be in itself expensive (can't you use arrays?), a quick numerical win is to only go up to the square root of the number in the inner loop.

`for (int j = 1; j * j <= i; j++)`

(Noting that squaring `j` is cheaper than the computing the square root of `i`, and keeps you away from floating point computations.)

This must be coupled with noting that if `j` is a divisor, then `i / j` is *also* a divisor. So you also need to replace

`divi[i][j] = true;`

with

`divi[i][j] = divi[i][i / j] = true;`

This optimisation is centred around the computation of the divisors of a *single* number. There are faster approaches for acquiring the divisors for a *set* of numbers, but my approach might be sufficient. Downvote if not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want: if you only want the common divisors for some specific numbers then the Euclidian algorithm is the solution.

If you really want a list of all divisors for all number 1..n, one solution would be (similar to a Sieve):

```
  for(int I=1;I<=sqrt(n);++I) {
     for(int j=I;j*I<=n;++j) divi[I*j][j]=divi[I*j][I]=true;
  }
```

The code complexity of the original one is O(N^2) with first answer it is O(N^1.5). I believe the new formula is O(N*log N)

Comment: And of course you can use I*I<=n instead of I<=sqrt(n); as suggested in other answer.